# How to update variable value of only the last created div with ng-repeat

Tags: html, css, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

In my html I have the following code:

```
<div ng-repeat="selection in selections" 
   style="margin-left:{{marginLeft}}%;width:{{progress}}%;background-color:{{selection}}">

</div>
```

And in my controller I have functions that update these values as such:

```
function calcExpenditure(expenditure, budget){
    $scope.progress = (expenditure/budget) * 100;
    if(count !== 0){
        $scope.marginLeft += $scope.progress;
    }
}
```

What's happening, which I did not anticipate as I should have, is that every time I run the `calcExpenditure` function, the `margin-left`, `width` and `background-color` properties are updated on divs where they have already been set.

How do I get Angular to update the values of these properties' scope variables in the controller and in the view only update it in the last created div by `ng-repeat`? Should I even be using `ng-repeat` or is there some other directive that would be better suited?

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `$last` special property of the `ng-repeat` directive

```
 <div ng-repeat="selection in selections track by $index" 
      style="{{($last?'margin-left:'+marginLeft+'%;
                    width:'+progress+'%;':'')+
               'background-color:'+selection}}">
 <br></div>
```

For more information on the `$last` special property see the [AngularJS ngRepeat API Reference](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat).

---

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'm getting an Unexpected end of input error, unsure of what is wrong as syntax looks correct to me.